# Upperbound on Shannon capacity of graph and strong product of graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, graph-colorings, combinatorial-optimization

Given a Graph $G = (V=[n],E)$, if a symmetric matrix $B$ fits $G$, it has non-zero diagonal elements and 0 on off-diagonal entries if $\{i,j\}$ are non-edge in $G$.
Let \begin{equation}
R(G) = \min Rank(B) \text{ } B_{ii}\ne 0, B_{ij}=0 (\{i,j\}\in \overline{G})
\end{equation}

1. show that $R(G*H)\leq R(G)R(H)$, where $R(G*H)$ is the strong product of $G$ and $H$.
2. show that $\Theta(G) \leq R(G)$.

I am not sure how to prove these, the second statement follows from the first one naturally, but how the ranks are related to each other?